# Texture Rendering Black, but shows up in textured view

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

My sword looks fine in solid view, but when I go into rendered view, it turns completely black.

I have mipmaps off, texture solid on.

It looks fine in solid view:

[image: intended coloring];

But when I switch to rendered view, the sword is entirely grey.

[image: rendered coloring].

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more information. What rendering engine are you using? Can you give some relevent screenshots of your material settings? a .blend file? We would be happy to answer your question, but it's important that we have the information nesisary.

Comment: You can upload a blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Screenshots me viewing the item (1st picture) then i change the viewport shading to rendered and looks like this (2nd picture) -just rendered POV-
http://imgur.com/R8Fivik,lscoBPT#0 Check the link for screenshots
I dont really understand "What rendering engine are you using?"

Comment: The blend file is likely to be of more use to those trying to help you than the screen shots. And when you upload the blend file, make sure to either pack the images you are using. One thing which might cause the phenomenon you describe is not having a lamp in the scene, or having one which is not oriented directly, or does not have enough strength.

Comment: The light is perfectly fine, i have linked other things into 1 scene so i can animate, the other objects are perfectly fine, but the sword is black.
Il send the file in a moment

Comment: "I don't really understand "What rendering engine are you using?" There are different engines you can use to render. If you look at the top of your screen, you'll see a drop down menu that says Blender Render. This dropdown is for choosing the rendering engine. The two options that are most used, are Blender Render, and Cycles. Cycles is more realistic, but don't worry about it right now.

Comment: Your going to have to post a .blend file. Use the service @GiantCowFilms linked to. We won't be able to help out with just screenshots, because you don't understand enough of the things that could be going wrong to show us what we need to see to help.

Comment: Are you sure you have lights in your scene? Thanks @brasshat for the edit :)

Comment: Since no one has yet done so yet, Alex, please let me welcome to the site. The part of your statement "...I have linked other things into one scene...", causes me to suggest that when you upload a ~.blend file, that you upload the file containing the original sword, not the scene containing the link. While there is a chance the problem may be the scene containing the link, the odds are the problem is in the vile which contains the native sword.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you don't have any lamps in your scene.

To add a lamp, you can press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to go to the add menu. Then go to lamp drop down, and select point. This will add a point light which casts light in all directions. After you add your light, just position it until it lights your sword well.

Comment: Generally you don't want to answer with one sentance like this. You always want to try to help explain why something is happening, and what can be done to fix it, etc.

Comment: no in this scene, im just showing what happens. But in the other scene where i have all my objects everything is fine without the sword

Comment: Thanks for trying to change it! I just submitted an edit, to show what I think could have been done better. It's mostly cleaning up the english, but there are a few other things I added to it. I hope you can see what I'm looking for.